# pass 2d array to wcf service in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have tried to pass an 2d array to a wcf service to connect to a database and return a 2d array to the client side to put data in list view but an error is raised: 2D arrays not supported

```
Function retreive(ByRef rows As Integer, ByRef colunms As Short, ByRef resarray(,) As String, ByVal identifier As Short) As Short Implements IService1.Retreive
    If (identifier = 0) Then
        Dim obj As New clsNews

        Return 0
    End If
```

Comment: Please add snippets of what you tried and specific description of the problem or error that is appearing, in order for others to help

Comment: I wrote this method
 Function retreive(ByRef rows As Integer, ByRef colunms As Short, ByRef resarray(,) As String, ByVal identifier As Short) As Short Implements IService1.Retreive
        If (identifier = 0) Then
            Dim obj As New clsNews

            Return 0
        End Ifbut when I run it it tells me that wcf doesn't support 2d array

Comment: please add the code to your question and not in a comment :)

Comment: I add it to the question

Comment: can you change the 2d array into a class for example that will give you same needed result ?

Comment: but how since I will pass an 2d array from client side to the service ?

Comment: I mean if you have control over the client side and server side, can you change the two sides to take classes that may achieve the required result, you can also add a sample of the data you want to send into question so others can suggest other form than 2d array since it is not supported

Comment: the data I want to process is a database rows , I do the 2d array way because it will be fit in 2d array , now I have to find anther way since its not supported

Comment: Try mapping the row into a class and try to send the values in form of List<MappedRow> , I think the list is supported, and good luck :)